# Many-to-one two-way communication of separate programs

Tags: c++, linux, named-pipes

I'm trying to make two-way many-to-one communication between programs in Linux.

My plan is the following: One program called "driver" that talks with the hardware needs to communicate with an unknown number of applications in Linux.
I read that one of the most common ways for inter process communication is "named pipes".

The question I haven't found yet is: How new programs should notify the driver that a new program is running so that one more connection (named pipe) between the new program and the driver enstablished?

All programs will be written in C++

[image]

Comment: I think sockets make more sense than pipes in this instance.  The driver process can listen on the loopback device, and the other processes can simply initiate a TCP connection when they need to talk to the driver.

Comment: I'm using a raspberry pi 2B that runs raspbian lite. I might be wrong but I think TCP sockets would be a little overhead for that purpose.

Comment: @MrBit A `AF_UNIX/AF_LOCAL` socket is not much more than a named pipe afaik and has all the nice features you'd want iike `select` support to create a truly event based driver. If you later decide to make it possible for other machines to connect (perhaps a driver from another Pi), your framework will be ready for it.

Comment: Yeah use a UNIX socket!

Comment: If you don't want full blown sockets, then you might look into [Unix Domain Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). They are one of the fastest Linux IPC mechanisms, and lightweight like named pipes.

Comment: If I chose to go with sockets, would I have to handle multiple clients or the OS would do that for me?

Comment: @MrBit Your driver will need to monitor the socket/pipe where incomming connections are made. When a new connection is made you need to keep track of the client somehow. A single threaded application just adds the client socket/pipe_fd to the list of file descriptors to monitor. A threaded application spawns a new thread which only cares about one client and syncing with the _server_ thread. A third option is to `fork` to separate the clients and server part completely. You need to choose one approach - and it'll be similar for sockets and pipes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thank you very much for your comment. My driver won't have to track client's state. Every program will just send some packets to the driver and driver will carry out everything needs to be done. It will remain in an "idle" state unless a packet received.

Comment: @MrBit Ok, just be aware of that you may get terrible performance if it can only serve one client at a time. If `N` clients tries to connect at the same time, the `N`:th client will have to want for the communication of the `N-1` first clients to be done becore your driver even accepts the connection / begins communicating.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm talking about multiple clients connected at the same time

Comment: @MrBit Ok, each connected client sends packets simultaneously. Will the driver be able to act on multiple packages at the same time before responding to the correct client?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure about that. I don't know anything about socket programming.

Comment: @MrBit It's a design descision you'll have to make. It doesn't matter if you use sockets or named pipes. If your driver should be able to handle incoming requests asynchronously, you'll need to keep track of which client to send the answer to somehow. It could be as simple as storing the file descriptor for the socket/pipe that you should send the response to together with the request. It also depends a little on if you go for a single thread, multithreaded or separate processes. Also note that with pipes, you'll have 2 file descriptors for each cllient. With sockets, only one.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I found that piece of code very good example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/ and I'm trying to learn a few things while I'm looking at it. I managed to made a very basic version of what I want to do using threads. Just put that code into a thread and my driver into another and so far I'm broadcasting some data to one client. Also, If I understood correctly I'll have to use `AF_UNIX/AF_LOCAL` instead of `AF_INET`. But I'm still strugling to gather the pieces of the puzzle togerther...

Comment: @MrBit Sounds great. Using `AF_UNIX` sockets makes communication potentially more effective, but I've never bothered and have always used `AF_INET`. Connecting to the same machine via the loopback (127.0.0.1) should be fairly effective too. You could also look at [boost::asio / Introduction to Sockets](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.htmlhttps://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) if you'd like some solid abstractions from the raw C interface to sockets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195209/discussion-between-mrbit-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also think sockets may be a better solution, but if you really want named pipes, I'd do it this way:

The server opens a pipe named `channel_request` for reading.  Any new client opens it for writing and writes a unique ID. (PID should work).  The server reads this id and creates a named pipe called `channel_[id]`.  The client then opens `channel_[id]` for reading and can start receiving data.

Note that linux pipes are unidirectional, so if you want two-way communications as shown in your diagram, you will need to open both a `channel_[id]_out` and  a `channel_[id]_in`.

Answer (score 5):

In essence, what you've described is a server/client relationship between programs; what each program does on either side of the communications bridge is probably irrelevant.

Even though these processes appear from the question to be intended to be on the same machine, networking is still available to you via localhost.

If you're not wedded to pipes, why not use a port for the driver (server) known to each program (client), to which the server listens?

That's pretty much the underlying philosophy of X-Windows, I believe.

Plus, there should be lots of reliable code out there to get you started.